# Verify Text of item in Listbox is the same one in List<string> C#

Tags: c#, .net, string, list, messagebox

I'm trying to get it to verify that it has the same item in the List as the one that's currently selected in the listbox

Why does this code not work, It should work unconditionally because the text generated from the listbox is taken from the List choicetitle

```
if (RemovePackages_Listbox.Text == choicetitle[RemovePackages_Listbox.SelectedIndex])
            {
                MessageBox.Show("The above code worked!");
            }
```

Comment: Output both of these using Response.Write, or attach a debugger.

Comment: That's the thing, there is no debug output, I think the if statement just isnt true so theres no error to report

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this

```
if (RemovePackages_Listbox.SelectedItem.ToString() == choicetitle[RemovePackages_Listbox.SelectedIndex])
            {
                MessageBox.Show("The above code worked!");
            }

else
{
    MessageBox.Show("RemovePackages_Listbox.SelectedItem.ToString() is "+RemovePackages_Listbox.SelectedItem.ToString()+" and choicetitle[RemovePackages_Listbox.SelectedIndex] is "+choicetitle[RemovePackages_Listbox.SelectedIndex]);
}
```

And tell us what you see in the popup messagebox?

Answer (score 0):

```
RemovePackages_Listbox.SelectedIndex
```

will return a zero-based index of the selected item in the ListBox.

So you're asking:

If the **text displayed in my Listbox** is the same as the **string in my ChoiceTitle List at position SELECTEDINDEX** -

Do this.

Triple check that.

Comment: I think he's just using SelectedIndex as the index of choiceTitle. There's nothing wrong with that.